# How to split string based on length and space using Java

Tags: java, split

I'm having a string as following in Java. The length of the string is not known and as an example it will be something like below.

```
String str = "I love programming. I'm currently working with Java and C++."
```

For some requirement I want to get first 15 characters. Then 30, 45, 70 next characters. Once the string was split if the name was not meaningful then it should be split from nearest space. For the above example output is as following.

```
String strSpli1 = "I love "; //Since 'programming' is splitting it was sent to next split
String strSpli2 = "programming. I'm currently ";//Since 'working'  is splitting it was sent to next split
String strSpli3 = "working with Java and C++.";
```

Please help me to achieve this.

Updated answer for anybody having this kind of requirement.

```
 String str = "I love programming. I'm currently working with Java and C++.";
                String strSpli1 = "";
                String strSpli2 = "";
                String strSpli3 = "";

    try {
                strSpli1 = str.substring(15);
                int pos = str.lastIndexOf(" ", 16);
                if (pos == -1) {
                    pos = 15;
                }
                strSpli1 = str.substring(0, pos);
                str = str.substring(pos);
    
                try {
                    strSpli2 = str.substring(45);
                    int pos1 = str.lastIndexOf(" ", 46);
                    if (pos1 == -1) {
                        pos1 = 45;
                    }
                    strSpli2 = str.substring(0, pos1);
                    str = str.substring(pos1);
    
                    try {
                        strSpli3 = str.substring(70);
                        int pos2 = str.lastIndexOf(" ", 71);
                        if (pos2 == -1) {
                            pos2 = 45;
                        }
                        strSpli3 = str.substring(0, pos2);
                        str = str.substring(pos2);
    
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        strSpli3 = str;
                    }
    
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    strSpli2 = str;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                strSpli1 = str;
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried yourself and is not working?

Comment: You can share what you have tried so far ? You can use the `indexOf` method of String class to find the next `space` characters that are near to your `length` of 30,45,70 and split the string using `substring`.

Comment: @Nisanth Reddy I have updated the question with the code that I've tried.

Comment: @AbRe you shouldn't just split based on length alone. Try doing it step by step. Split  with the first length `30`. Then check this substring that you have split if it is breaking a word in the middle. If it is breaking the word, then find the two nearest ` ` in your string using `indexOf`. Once you have those 2 indices, you can decide which one to choose and update your new substring. Then you can proceed to the next `length` you want and repeat the same process until you reach the end of the string.

Comment: How do you decide "_if the name was not meaningful_" ?

Comment: @PalLaden based on space. If it's splitting a word then the sentence is not meaningful. That's my assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the 2 parameter version of `lastIndexOf()` to search for space backwards starting from a given position. Example for the first 15 characters:

```
int pos = str.lastIndexOf(" ", 16);
if (pos == -1) {
    pos = 15;
}
String found = str.substring(0, pos);
str = str.substring(pos+1);
```

this is missing checks like ensuring the string starts with at least 15 characters, or that `pos+1` is valid for given length

---

suggest having a look at [`java.text.BreakIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/BreakIterator.html)

Answer (score -1):

why you use so many try catch ? just try this.

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str = "I love programming. I'm currently working with Java and C++.";
    String strSpli1 = "";
    String strSpli2 = "";
    String strSpli3 = "";
    strSpli1 = str.substring(0, 7);
    strSpli2 = str.substring(7, 33);
    strSpli3 = str.substring(34, str.length());
   

     System.out.println(strSpli1+"\n");
     System.out.println(strSpli2+"\n");
     System.out.println(strSpli3+"\n");

}
```

use substring(start index, end index).

Comment: because I don't know the length of the string. If the length is less than 15 it will throw an exception

Comment: use this for know how many of length , str.length()

Comment: do you mean your input is general or dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic input and sometimes it will have less than 15 length